# Ionic stop video after tab switch

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, html5-video

I have an ionic videos app, i'm using  tag to play videos, i have a tab menu i would like to achieve these things :

- Stop videos after i switch tabs because sounds are overlapping.
- Mute the videos (the "mute" attribute is not working)
- I have a video tag inside an avatar tag to preview videos in loop, the application crashes when there are too many videos playing at once, what is the best way to achieve this task.

Tried to add the mute attribute to video tag but it's ignored, tried to programmatically stop videos but it doesn't work. I don't know how to implement the avatar video previews, i just put a video tag instead of the img tag and play it in a loop.

Thank you so much.

Comment: What, specifically, have you tried? See how to compose a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @LisaJ Thank you, i updated the question